# Request JSON Alamofire GET

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have a question respect to make request with Alamofire to request GET...Because when i send the request, my server , receive three request, and that request are empty ....I use Alamofire and use One Router , **"I send my parameters in json"**

```
 case .SearchTravel (let pa1,let pa2,let pa3,let pa4):

                let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {

                    let parameters = [
                        "startLat": "12",
                        "startLng": "12",
                        "endLat": "12",
                        "endLng": "21",
                    ]
                    println(Router.tokenUser)
                    println(parameters)
                    return ("travels/Search/", parameters)
                }()

                let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)



                let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(
                                URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))

                //---
                URLRequest.HTTPMethod="GET"

                if let token = Router.tokenUser {
                    URLRequest.setValue(

                        "Token \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField:
                        "Authorization")

                    println(token)
                }

                let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON

                return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

And when i call to router ...

```
Django.Router.tokenUser=userLogin.token

Alamofire.request(Django.Router.SearchTravel("23", "32", "32", "32")).responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
            if error==nil{
                println("Ok")
            }
            else{

                println(error)

                }
```

But i dont know if I'm doing well the request or what is the problem...

Or what is the way to build a json request?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let parameters = [
            "startLat": "12",
            "startLng": "12",
            "endLat": "12",
            "endLng": "21",
        ]
        let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: nil)

        let post = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String

        httpPost("http://httpbin.org/post", postData: post) {res, c in
            println(res)
        }


func httpPost(url:String, postData: String, completion: (String, Int) -> Void) {

        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.HTTPBody = postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")
        request.addValue("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("gzip, deflate, sdch", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
        request.addValue("max-age=0", forHTTPHeaderField: "Cache-Control")

        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode

            completion(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String, statusCode)
            }
        })

        task.resume()

    }
```

You can modify function as you wish. I've tested in via httpbin and saw the result:
[image]